# Aptana color syntax for jsp

Tags: jsp, aptana

Is it possible for Aptana to do color syntax for jsp files?  How?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by editing the preferences, go to preferences > General > editors

select the *.jsp from file types, you can view the associated editors, select the HTML editor and make it default by clicking the default button at the right side

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you want to do syntax coloring in Studio 2 or Studio 3.

In Studio 2, you can define custom .lxr and .col files to both lex and colorize a specific file:

http://docs.aptana.com/dev/index.php/Colorizing_an_Editor

You then associate those with the "Generic Text Editor" (See Preferences).

In Studio 3, there is no similar mechanism yet. There's a ticket for it, but no ETA.

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/2136-support-custom-colorization-of-arbitrary-files